# Include codeigniter page into non-codeigniter php page

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, include

I am working on a CMS that instead of generates pages automatically, it generates code and gives it to the user to add to their php page.

I am in the process of moving the application to CI but struggling with how to set up this process.

By making 2 codeigniter index pages (one for the main application and the other for connecting which changes the initial controller and index path) this almost works, what I would desire would be something like this:

```
<?php include("cms/connector.php"); ?>
<html>
..
<body>
<h1>Static</h1>
<?php echo($cms['data']); ?>
</body>
```

It pulls the file correctly and runs the view that is called, but the variables from the view are not saved.

Also I need the ability to target the cms page they are trying to get, however:

```
<?php include("cms/connector.php/cms/2"); ?>
```

No longer works (I guess because there is no extension?) If I could get this part to work I wouldn't need to worry about the variables since I could just include the view directly on the page

Any ideas would be great

The application could be hosted on various setups, so I would like it if I could bypass the need to include the direct url (http) since it might not always be turned on by default. Also I don't want to pull with ajax since I want the content to be picked up well by search engines

Comment: Can you clarify "it pulls the file correctly and runs the view that is called, but the variables from the view are not saved."  What do you mean by the variables from the view?  do you mean when a form is submitted?  Or do you mean that the variables in your view file are not displayed?  What do you also mean by "2 codeigniter index pages"?  Do you mean two controllers?

Comment: Sorry, when I say the variables are not saved I just mean that they are not transferred to the page including them but the view is working if I echo something in the view it shows on the page. I wouldn't expect the variables to be passed anyway but not sure there is a way to pass them over to the file including them.

Comment: I was messing with two code igniter index pages (the root index page) to try and have a second one go to a different controller just by visiting /cms/index2.php instead because of my second issue, where the include only seems to be working for the index page and not any controllers afterward

Comment: I'm confused why you are visiting two index.php files.  Codeigniter uses url's to specify controller/function/argument.  If you have a need to direct a user to another "page", why aren't you sending them to a specific controller and function to load the view you want to show them?  This may be why your variables aren't being displayed...are you using $this->load->view('myview',$data_to_send_to_view);?

Comment: The script I'm working with is not in codeigniter. My codeigniter cms app will ideally spit out code that the user puts on their web page. That code will pull the content from mysql.

Comment: So when the user goes to mysite.com/cms, the cms app is using CI for the entire application (main index.php).  My attempt with the second index file might not even be necessary if I can find a work around but it was for when the user is putting the code on their website (on the same server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's [cURL module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Below is taken from the examples in the documentation.

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/cms/connector.php/cms/2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Note that this will pull the ENTIRE document, including doctype, `<head>`, etc. This is not what you want if you're including this in another page. You probably want to modify `connector.php` to output only the body of the document..

Comment: Really ... this is what you would do ?

Comment: What would be the downsides to this? Since this would be hosted on different setups, is this slow or disabled often?

Comment: Its really not the way to go in My Opinion, I would rather create an API Access layer from Site B. Ill re up vote your down vote as I was not clear on the separate hosting situation, your answer is viable.

Comment: The hosting would be the same, I'm sure there's a different way to go though. I might just need to write the connector script outside of CI all together :/

Answer (score 0):

**Sounds like you are designing an api.**

(And I'm not sure why you are using CI for half of it and custom scripts for the rest.  CI can accomodate your needs.)

The following suggestion might be obvious or outside of your expected answers, but on the off-chance it helps, I wanted to put it on the table.

If I understand your question and comments correctly, you have users who have sites on your server.  You also have an application that gives them code that they paste into their site that somehow works with information on your server.

1. You need a controller that receives requests for information from the pasted code
2. You need a way to authenticate the request
3. The user provides some kind of variable information
4. You need to return information or html upon successful validation, based on variables provided by the user.

Codeigniter allows you to work with segment based url's or with query strings.  It prefers and works out of the [box with segments, but can be configured to work with query strings](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

You may construct a url that contains

1. the name of a controller and function to process the request (instead of the second index page you mentioned
2. a token for authenticating the request.  This would ideally be used to compare to information stored in the db when the token is created and issued to the user.  Check out this article: http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/01/rest-api-authentication-schemes and this one too:  http://oauth.net/
3. information provided by the user

An example:

```
"example.com/cms/(index.php)/connector/function-name/auth-token/user-info"
```

Once your controller processes the request, return the information to the user.

Comment: It would be the other way around, the user downloads my cms app and adds it to their server. The idea is they don't need to overhaul their website in order for it to have dynamic content. My app would give them the code that pulls dynamic content into their pre-existing web page. I think I may just need to write a separate external script that just does any needed calls to the db and assembles content instead of working with code igniter

Answer (score -1):

Codeigniter routes the application depending on the environment state of the URI

What you need to do is set the environment and include the index view file like so:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = "cms/2";

//Set GET action,method params etc

require_once "path/to/index.php";
```

When you load CI Index file it reads the SERVER Variable and others which you may have to find and execute the controller and method, i would also advise that you modify the library/view file as it may exit upon output causing your script to exit.

Also you may wis hto look into `ob_start()` etc to catch the buffer

Comment: It seems to just stay at the index page even though I'm setting the server var (CI outputting -No URI data exists).

Comment: One other issue I may run into is the user might wish to include 2 blocks of text on one page (maybe a block of content for the about page and using a block for the footer of the page)